# Change the separator in Zsh %_

Tags: zsh, prompt

When setting PROMPT2, I can add %_ to show `for if` or `for then` when I'm in these constructs. Is there any way to change the space to be something else, e.g. show `for/if` or `for:if` or even `for -> if` instead of the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `promptsubst` option enabled, you could do:

```
$ PS2='${${(%):-%_}// / -> }> '
$ for i
for> if
for -> if>
```

`${(%)...}` enables prompt expansion on the expansion of `...`. `${:-text}` allows to have a `${...}` expand arbitrary text. And we apply the `${x//pat/reply}` substitution on it. That assumes the expansion of `%_` doesn't itself include `%` characters.